# how to set transform for div without effect on background image?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a Parallelogram object by flat (true) background-image .

HTML:

```
<div class="q-item"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.q-item {
    width: 180px;
    height: 132px;
    background:url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png') no-repeat no-repeat 13px 1px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 58px;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border: 2px solid #1D2A3D;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

please see my sample at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh7qyt07/1/)

how to set transform for `div` without effect on object's on this element and whiteout effect at this background?

Comment: Rahul this questins not help to me.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289643/how-do-i-unskew-background-image-in-skewed-layer-css

Comment: yes! it's like showdev answer and it working good. :) thanks and this question will be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success by adding a pseudo-element `::before`, moving the `background-image` to that pseudo-element, and applying a reversed skew to counteract your original skew.

This is based on a solution at [sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/).

```css
.q-item {
    width: 180px;
    height: 132px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 58px;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border: 2px solid #1D2A3D;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.q-item::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png') no-repeat no-repeat 33px 1px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bh7qyt07/3/)

Comment: The question has been flagged as a duplicate. The duplicate post has an answer similar to mine. I'll delete my answer in a few minutes.